# Plot CIE-1931 Chromaticity Graph with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas

Trying to figure out how to plot a CIE-1931 diagram with CSS and or Canvas.  A couple ideas

1. Use an svg clipping mask on the spectrum locust
2. Plot it manually with js and canvas

The main problem in the xyz color space in css, it appears to clip at srgb even though it should cover even implausible colors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<style>
.cie-diagram {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey
}

.cie-square {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, color(xyz-d65, 0, 0, 1) 0%, color(xyz-d65, 0, 1, 1) 100%);
}

.cie-square::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, color(xyz-d65, 1, 0, 1) 0%, color(xyz-d65, 1, 1, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0, white 100%);
  mask: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0, white 50%, transparent 100%);
}

</style>
</head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cie-diagram">
       <div class="cie-square"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it related to the C language? Do not spam tags!!  Removing the `C` tag

Comment: @0___________ that is CSS not C

Comment: **I deleted** the `C` tag!!! https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Vez.png